# ERROR 1064 error de sintaxis en stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
mysql> create procedure evaluaExistencia (in idP int)
    -> begin
    -> declare E int;
    -> select existencia from productos where idProducto = idP into E;
    -> if (E > 0) then
    -> select nobre, precio, existencia from productos where idProducto = idP;
    -> else if(E = 0) then
    -> select p.nombre as producto_similar, p.precio, p.existencia, pr.nombre as proveedor
    -> from productos p inner join  proveedores pr on p.idProveedor = pr.idProveedor where p.idProveedor = idP;
    -> end $$
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10
mysql>

Comment: Where's your `end if` bits?

Comment: exactly that's the problem. I have already solved it